# How to bind the wpf datagrid scrollviewer visiblity to button visibility?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

```
<Window x:Class="WPfDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgrdEmployee" Width="300" Height="300" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
            <Button Content="Navigation" x:Name="BtnNavigation" Width="90" Height="40" Margin="204,336,209,-15" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public class Employees
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Employees> EmployeeList()
    {
        XDocument employees = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Employees.xml");
        List<Employees> employee = (from em in employees.Descendants("Employee")
                                    select new Employees
                                    {
                                        Name = em.Element("Name").Value,
                                        Id = em.Element("Id").Value,
                                        Address = em.Element("Address").Value
                                    }).ToList();
        return employee;
    }
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgrdEmployee.ItemsSource = EmployeeList();
    }
}
```

with above code, i get the following result.

[image]

If the data grid scroll viewer is visible the button should be visible, otherwise button should be collapse. Is there any change to do so ?

I tried something like below. But it won't make sense to me.

```
<Button Content="Navigation" x:Name="BtnNavigation" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=dgrdEmployee.ScrollViewer}" Width="90" Height="40" Margin="204,336,209,-15" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ScrollViewer` is always visible. The `ScrollViewer` will show or hide its scrollbars depending on how much data is shown.

Assuming that you can get to the `VerticalScrollBarVisiblity` and `HorizontalScrollBarVisiblity` properties of the `ScrollViewer`, you could probably create a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) between those properties and the button's `Visibliity` property. You would probably also have to create a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), since the scroll bar visibility properties use a different type (that includes an `Auto` value in addition to the standard visibility values).